# Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key / Child keys must be unique

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron

Yesterday I added `react-router-dom` to my project and now when I leave and come back to my `Sky` element in my nav, it reloads the sky and I get

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `element-id-50`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

*(the number 50 used above is just an example, it throws this error ~40 times each time all with different ids)*

The problem seems to stem from here in my `sky.js` file:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(requestSkySetup());
    this.props.dispatch(requestAllElements());

    this.setState({loadedSky: true, loadedElements: true});
}
```

Since each time I'm going to another screen, this component is unmounting and then re-mounting when I come back.

When `receiveSkySetup` is finished, the `render` function in `sky.js` creates a bunch of divs called `Sector`s and each `Sector` creates a few divs called `Slot`s.

Then inside of `Slot.render` I have:

```
return connectDropTarget(
            <div className={showOutline ? 'slot showOutline' : 'slot'} style={style} onClick={interactable ? this.handleClick : null}>
                {
                    elements
                        .map(e => (
                            <SkyElement
                                id={e.id}
                                key={`element-id-${e.id}`}
                                title={e.title}
                                size={150}
                                opacity={e.opacity}
                                glow={e.glow}
                                color={e.color}
                                sectorId={e.sectorId}
                                slotId={e.id}
                                dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                                isDragging={false}
                                transformElement={false} />
                        ))
                }
            </div>
        );
```

The `key` element in the `SkyElement` call above is what's throwing the 40+ errors on each mounting.

Happy to provide more code if needed.

Any help would be hugely helpful. Thanks!

**Edit: Console logging elements**

Digging in a bit more, the items are doubling in my store.

So, on the 2nd render of the `sky` tab, the full list of element ids is `["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "17", "18", "19", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "77", "78", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "17", "18", "19", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "77", "78"]`

On the 3rd render, elements 0-78 (the ids that apply from the array above) will be added again to the array

In `Slot.js`

```
const mapStateToProps = ({elements}, ownProps) => {
    return {
        elements: getElementsBySlotId(elements, ownProps.id),
    };
};
```

`elements` here will be `n` times the number of loads that `Sky` has done.

In `sky.js`

```
const mapStateToProps = ({sky, elements}) => {
    return {
        sectors: getSky(sky).sectors,
        elements: getElementsByKeyName(elements, 'visibleElements'),
        unplacedElements: getElementsByKeyName(elements, 'unplacedElements'),
    };
};
```

Printing `elements.length` I see that they double here too. Slot.js is pulling from the same store, so that makes sense

In my `elements/reducer.js`

```
case 'receiveAllElements':
        const visibleElements = {};
        const unplacedElements = {};

        const elements = action.elements.reduce((result, index) => {
            result[`${index.id}`] = index;
            return result;
        }, {});

        const keys = Object.keys(elements);
        for (const key of keys) {
            const e = elements[key];

            if (e.sectorId === null) {
                unplacedElements[key] = e;
            } else {
                visibleElements[key] = e;
            }
        }

        const visibleIds = Object.keys(visibleElements);
        const unplacedIds = Object.keys(unplacedElements);
        console.log(visibleIds);
        console.log(unplacedIds); // logging these, the numbers are consistent and don't double, triple etc with each load

        return {
            ...state,
            elementsMap: {
                ...state.elementsMap,
                ...elements,
            },
            visibleElements: [...state.visibleElements, ...visibleIds],
            unplacedElements: [...state.unplacedElements, ...unplacedIds],
        };
```

Maybe something in there is causing the count to double?

Comment: Have you tried `.map((e, index) => (` and `key={index}` ?

Comment: I haven't but I'm not sure it would make a difference. For example, when I unmount and remount the Sky element, the error is thrown again for element-id-50 and if i repeat it, the error will happen again for 50. I imagine the same would happen with index

Comment: Is each slot rendering the same `elements`?

Comment: Each slot renders a uniq element or set of elements. There is no overlap

Comment: can you update on how is the elements array populated?

Comment: It's pulled from the redux store which is filled as the result of the call to the server to get all unique elements for a user

Comment: how about ``key={`${e.id}-${e.sectorId}`}``?

Comment: I believe the issue here is that something is going on maybe with redux, not sure, where when the component is re-mounted, there's some existing record of the key somewhere. The ids are all unique, so adding the sectorId won't help

Comment: @Andrew I tried your approach. Each time I come back to the Sky view from the other views, it adds an other element in each slot that wasn't there before (which obviously isn't ideal)

Comment: @free-soul tried your approach as well, same bug as in the original post

Comment: When you remove `connectDropTarget`, do the warnings disappear?

Comment: Nope, they're still there after removing `connectDropTarget`

Comment: @ZackShapiro take a look at the `elements` array maybe the are items with equal `e.id`.

Comment: All elements in the array have a unique id. The server-side validation wouldn't allow a new element to be created with an existing id

Comment: @ZackShapiro Do you use react-css-modules?

Comment: @hinok No, I do not

Comment: @ZackShapiro does `this.props.dispatch(requestSkySetup());` populate your store with the sky elements by pushing them to an array? If so, I bet your store is not being cleaned when your component unmounts. So when it mounts again you have duplicate data in your store.

Comment: Can you simply show use the console.log(elements) of when the warning happens? as the only reason there is same id...

Comment: @TzookBarNoy Updating the original post with more info

Comment: `result[\`${index.id}\`]` → `result[index.id]` 

Comment: ooof, old code. Gross. Fixed that. Not the source of the problem though

Comment: You could also try `action.elements.reduce((result, current, index) => ({ ...result, [index]: current }), {})`, but I'm not sure it'd make any sense. 

Comment: Is the issue in the `return`ed object? is it doubling the values in there?

Comment: Generally, object spread operation is super safe against duplicates. The language itself makes sure there are no duplicate keys in an object, it's just impossible. However, it's not true for arrays. This operation may produce duplicate _values_ in the array: `[...state.visibleElements, ...visibleIds]`. Given that you do `getElementsByKeyName(elements, 'visibleElements')`, that might be the cause.

Comment: Looks like I was able to fix it by changing the array to just `[...visibleIds]`. Is there a better solution than that or is that the one? Thanks for your help @RishatMuhametshin

Comment: Do you want to leave an answer so I can give you the bounty? Thanks

Comment: No problem and no need in this bounty thing! But regarding a better way to keep unique values in arrays, there's a good answer on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121880/1287643

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin, Please, answer on your question to people know your problem has a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here was

```
    return {
        ...state,
        elementsMap: {
            ...state.elementsMap,
            ...elements,
        },
        visibleElements: [...state.visibleElements, ...visibleIds],
        unplacedElements: [...state.unplacedElements, ...unplacedIds],
    };
```

namely, the `visibleElements` (and `unplacedElements` values).

`[...state.visibleElements, ...visibleIds]` will concat 2 arrays so since this code was being hit each time I went back to the `Sky` tab, it was adding the new ids in `...visibleIds`, to the array I already had in `...state.visibleElements` and doubling values